# How to reclaim space in Citrix Xenserver's root filesystem?

Tags: xenserver, citrix

On Citrix Xenserver 6.2, when the root filesystem is about to be full, what can be done to reclaim space?

So far, I deleted logs but I'd like to go further. Is it safe to delete files in '/var/patch/'   as long as I don't remove anything in '/var/patch/applied'?

Thanks,

Greg.

Answer (score 1):

If I look on a XEN Server 6.2 root disk here I see that the disk is only 4gb.

Possible solution:

**Resize swap file**
I went through the disk and found out that the swap file is 512mb, which is 12.5%. The swap file is in my case not in use at all, so maybe you can tweak it to be smaller. Don't just delete it in a production environment.

I cannot confirm that deleting the patches will help you.